# SwiftUI HStack with GeometryReader and paddings

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my iOS App i want to place two views of the same width so that they fill the entire width of the parent view.

For this I use GeometryReader and it broke auto layout. But auto layout does not work and the height of this view is not calculated automatically. Height of TestView is not determined, so i cant add frame size manually...

Here's what it should look like (what i expect **TestView**):

[image: TestView]

This is what it looks like when I put a view on a list (**CurrenciesView**):

[image: CurrenciesView]

TestView.swift

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0.0) {
                    Text("Name 1\n Test second name 2")
                        .font(.system(size: 18))
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    HStack {
                        Text("123")
                        Text(" + 5")
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 12.0)
                .padding(.vertical, 9.0)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2)
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8.0)
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue
                                    .opacity(0.2)))

                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0.0) {
                    Text("Name 1")
                        .font(.system(size: 18))
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    HStack {
                        Text("123")
                        Text(" + 5")
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 12.0)
                .padding(.vertical, 9.0)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2)
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8.0)
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue
                                    .opacity(0.2)))
            }
        }

    }
}
```

CurrenciesView.swift

```
struct CurrenciesView: View {

    @State private var items: [Str] = (0..<5).map { i in

       return Str(title: "Struct  #\(i)")

    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                    List {
                        Section(header:
                        TestView().listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                        ) {
                            ForEach(items) { item in
                                Text("asd")
                            }
                        }.clipped()

                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle("Section Name")
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom `PreferenceKey` and a view that calculates it:

```
struct ViewSizeKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero

    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

```
struct ViewGeometry: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Color.clear
                .preference(key: ViewSizeKey.self, value: geometry.size)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can use them in your views. Note that you need to use `@Binding` in the `TestView` and `@State private var headerSize` in the parent view. Otherwise the parent view won't be refreshed and the List won't re-calculate the header size properly.

```
struct CurrenciesView: View {
    @State private var items: [String] = (0 ..< 5).map(String.init)
    @State private var headerSize: CGSize = .zero

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header:
                    TestView(viewSize: $headerSize)
                ) {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }.clipped()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Section Name")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct TestView: View {
    @Binding var viewSize: CGSize

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0.0) {
                Text("Name 1\n Test second name 2")
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                HStack {
                    Text("123")
                    Text(" + 5")
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 12.0)
            .padding(.vertical, 9.0)
            .frame(width: viewSize.width / 2)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8.0)
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue
                    .opacity(0.2)))

            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0.0) {
                Text("Name 1")
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                HStack {
                    Text("123")
                    Text(" + 5")
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 12.0)
            .padding(.vertical, 9.0)
            .frame(width: viewSize.width / 2)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8.0)
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue
                    .opacity(0.2)))
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(ViewGeometry()) // calculate the view size
        .onPreferenceChange(ViewSizeKey.self) {
            viewSize = $0 // assign the size to `viewSize`
        }
    }
}
```